# Maximal ideals of $\Bbb R[x,y]/(x^2+1,y^2-1)$

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals

My problem is finding all maximal ideals of the commutative ring $\Bbb R[x,y]/(x^{2}+1,y^{2}-1)$.

I'm aware of the statement that maximal ideals of $\Bbb R[x,y]/(x^{2}+1,y^{2}-1)$ are the same as maximal ideals of $\Bbb R[x,y]$ containing $(x^{2}+1,y^{2}-1)$. It is standard that $\Bbb R[x,y]=(\Bbb R[x])[y]$. Since $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^{2}+1,y^{2}-1) = \left(\mathbb{R}[y]\right)[x]/(x^{2}+1,y^{2}-1) $, we can apply the third isomorphism theorem to say that:
$$
\left(\mathbb{R}[y]\right)[x]/(x^{2}+1,y^{2}-1) \cong \frac{\left(\mathbb{R}[y]\right)[x]/(x^{2}+1)}{(x^{2}+1,y^{2}-1)/(x^{2}+1)}
$$
The numerator is isomorphic to some filed $F[y]$ since $x^2+1$ is irreducible (?) in $\left(\mathbb{R}[y]\right)[x]$, and the bottom is the ideal $(y^2-1)$ in that ring, so we indeed have $F[y]/(y^{2}-1)$. 
By [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert's_Nullstellensatz)'s theorem, all ideals are of the form $(y-a)$ for real number $a$ such that $a^2-1=0$ which forces $a=\pm1$.
We conclude that $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^{2}+1,y^{2}-1)$ has $2$ maximal ideals: $(y\pm1)/(y^{2}-1)$.

I'm not sure whether the above solution is correct since $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ but what about $\left(\mathbb{R}[y]\right)[x]$? Using Hilbert's Nullstellensatz's theorem may be an overkill however it is an useful tool in general. Please light up my mind by your comments.

Comment: This ring is isomorphic to $\Bbb C[y] / (y^2 - 1)$.

Comment: ... and maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[y]$ are all of the form $(y-a)$ for some $a\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: @Travis How can you conclude that?

Comment: The ring is isomorphic to $$(R[x,y] / (x^2 + 1) ) / (y^2 - 1) \cong (R[x] / (x^2 + 1))[y] / (y^2 - 1),$$ but $x^2 + 1$ is an irreducible quadratic over $\Bbb R$, so $\Bbb R[x] / (x^2 + 1) \cong \Bbb C$ (via the map that identifies the image of $x$ under the projection $\Bbb R[x] \to \Bbb R[x] / (x^2 +1)$ with $i$).

Comment: @Travis Ok I see. How about my last answer? Are the desired maximal ideals $(y\pm1)/(y^{2}-1)$?

Comment: Yes, I think so.